# How to remove Launcher and go back to desktop icons?

Tags: launcher, icons

So can I go back to the old Menu Desktop.

I would like the old desktop like in 9.04

Answer (score 0):

I believe I can help you two entirely different way, either of which may make you very happy.  I believe the easier though less elegant solution is for you to downgrade to [LUBUNTU](http://lubuntu.net/) which is pretty much exactly what you've asked for.  LUBUNTU is Ubuntu Light, with the minimal graphical (gnome) interface you are seeking.

~~~

I hope you LIKE my solution above, and won't hold it against me that I would like to introduce you to a not-entirely-obvious FEATURE of the Unity interface I'm really incredibly fond of, and I'm concerned you might have missed.

Pause for a moment and think about those programs you only use once or twice a year, that you can barely remember the names of and have to hunt around to find when you actually need them again?

What would you say if I told you that Unity makes it possible to find the software you want on your own pc, even if you can't remember what it's called.  Try this exercise, tap the windows key on your keyboard and see the HUD.  Tap it again and it disappears.

Tap again and at the prompt type EDIT.  Everything that edits appears for you to choose from.  Press ESC to clear the prompt.  Type CD and every program that deals with optical media appears.  Next time try DOC and every program that reads or creates MS WORD format documents appears.

On another website I recently commented that even when I cannot persuade windows users to try ubuntu, they always agree that windows would be easier to use if it had the Unity interface.  I'm hoping you'll give it another try, but if not, I hope you at least like my LUBUNTU suggestion.